# What is the geometric interpretation of quadratic forms?

Tags: geometry, quadratic-forms

I am trying to make sense of the following condition:

Let $w_1, \dots, w_m \in \mathbb{C}^d$ with $\|w_i\| \le 1$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^m \, |\langle u, w_i \rangle |^2 = n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{R}$ and *any* unit vector $u$.

Geometrically speaking, what does this condition tell me about my $w_i$ vectors?

Comment: Not sure if this helps; it's just a thought. Taking the $w_i$ as rows of a matrix $W\in\mathbb C^{m\times d}$, you get $$\sum_{i=1}^m\left\lvert\left<u,w_i\right>\right\rvert^2=\left\lVert W\cdot u\right\rVert^2 = n$$ For $d=m$ you could probably conclude interesting stuff from this.

Answer (score 1):

The first condition $\|w_i\|\leq 1$ means that all of your $w_i$ lie on or inside the unit ball. Easy enough.

The second is basically saying, "pick a direction, and take the component of the vectors that lie in that direction. Add up the squares of these components, and they have to add up to $n$."

To me that suggests that the $w_i$ are somewhat evenly distributed, direction wise.